# The original size of my image in flutter is smaller than the Container's container and it reports an error when I set it as a background image

Tags: flutter

Please tell me that in flutter my image original size is smaller than Container's   and when I set it as background image it will report an error. How do I fix it?

**Example**

```
Container(
                    width: 500,
                    height: 200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('lib/assets/images/home/xn.webp'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

**Error**

```
════════ Exception caught by painting library ══════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown while painting an image:
Image lib/assets/images/home/xn.webp has a display size of 1290×600 but a decode size of 1412×960, which uses an additional 3028KB.

Consider resizing the asset ahead of time, supplying a cacheWidth parameter of 1290, a cacheHeight parameter of 600, or using a ResizeImage.

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbCce.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here i am assuming you have a image which dimensions are 500×200 but you are rendering image at dimensions 1024×400, which is a heavy workfor flutter. so flutter is suggesting you specify the image dimension before it set to any widget.

```
Container(
          height: 500,
          width: 200,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            child: AssetImage('lib/assets/images/home/xn.webp),
          ),
        );
      }
```

link = https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html